# Best fit with GLM in R

Tags: r, regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, descriptive-statistics

I'm trying to know what is the best GLM fit with this simple dataset and tests in R:

```
a=c(1.168668,1.467459,1.357719,1.253049,1.205406,1.395816,1.302802,1.268686,1.257424,1.155373,1.049089,1.077470);
b=c(0.664,0.523,0.511,0.558,0.603,0.644,0.480,0.561,0.562,0.686,0.651,0.623);
c=c(0.699,0.585,0.573,0.602,0.660,0.666,0.566,0.627,0.638,0.699,0.706,0.672);
r=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);


dataset <- data.frame(a,b,c,r)

#First test
mfit0 <- glm(data=dataset,formula=a~b/c);

#Second test
mfit1 <- glm(data=dataset,formula=a~b);
```

`mfit0` summary returns:

```
Deviance Residuals: 
      Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max  
-0.131345  -0.018809  -0.003038   0.038533   0.119793  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  -0.2754     0.8713  -0.316   0.7591  
b             8.2938     3.6341   2.282   0.0484 *
b:c          -8.8360     3.3800  -2.614   0.0281 *

Null deviance: 0.170905  on 11  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 0.060651  on  9  degrees of freedom
AIC: -21.396
```

and `mfit1` summary returns:

```
Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-0.12962  -0.03927  -0.01512   0.02112   0.21300  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   1.9272     0.2791   6.905 4.17e-05 ***
b            -1.1559     0.4712  -2.453   0.0341 *  
    Null deviance: 0.17091  on 11  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 0.10671  on 10  degrees of freedom
AIC: -16.616
```

Then I try to apply a `wald.test` (Test of WALD), where:

**mfit0**:

`chi2=16.36 and p-value=0.0003`

**mfit1**:

`chi2=6.01 and p-value=0.0142`

So, What is the best model or what is the model fits it better?.
Is `p-value` from `mfit0` and `Wald test` good o better than `mfit1`?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not understand your question since both models have different dependent variables and are therefore not comparable.

Comment: Ok, true ! Let me change

Comment: Why do you use a Gaussian GLM and not simply an OLS model?

Comment: @Roland, Im trying this model right now. Before I tried `lm` models, but I want to learn if glm works better for my small dataset.

Comment: No, a Gaussian GLM won't work better. Apart from the numerics (which can make it worse), the results should be identical.

Comment: So, @Roland , what do you recommend? Only a few values , could be not good .

Comment: You actual goal is not defined. Thus, there is nothing that can be recommended.

Comment: My goal roland is to know if `a` is modelled by  `b` or `b/c` , and if is `b` or `b/c` better for it, @Roland

Comment: Define "better". Apparently your actual goad is prediction?

Comment: Ok, call it prediction @Roland.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly is your goal? Is it to assess the predictive ability of each model?

If it is, you could always try cross-validation. Or else split the dataset into training and testing data(70/30), and compare them. Although you'll need a bigger dataset to really see any sort of comparable difference I'd say

Comment: My goal are two: 1st: check if use `b` or `b/c` is better or not to define `a`. and 2nd: if can I predict the value (regression) of `a` with `b` or `c`